# Different output when getting value from a 2D array using different way

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

When I try to getting output from a 2D array with this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(MatrixProb()));
```

I get this output (which is what I want).

```
[[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.07692307692307693, 0.15384615384615385, 0.46153846153846156, 0.23076923076923078, 0.07692307692307693, 0.0], 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5]]
```

But when I try to make the output look easier to read, with this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.printf("row %d: ", i+1);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%.2f", MatrixProb()[i][j]);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Instead, I get this output

```
row 1: 0,00 1,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 
row 2: 0,00 0,34 0,34 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,32 0,00 0,00 0,00 
row 3: 0,00 0,00 0,00 1,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 
row 4: 0,00 0,50 0,00 0,50 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 
row 5: 1,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 
row 6: 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,50 0,50 0,00 0,00 0,00 
row 7: 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,08 0,15 0,46 0,23 0,08 0,00 
row 8: 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,50 0,50 0,00 0,00 
row 9: 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 1,00 
row 10: 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,50 0,00 0,50
```

You could see in the row 2, the output is different. Is there anything wrong with my second way? Or maybe do you know how to properly make 2D array output look readable in the IDE output?

Comment: Please provide a minmal reproducable example. From the code you have shown, I cant recreate the problem, to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i'm very sorry for that. the `matrixProb()`  it self is dependent on other method which the (other method ) also dependent on others. i'll be right back with more proper question.

Comment: I suggest you to extract the invocation to `MatrixProbe` **out** of both loops, and store it in a local variable instead. From what we know, that method could be returning different values on each invocation.